# Unable to store image in PouchDB--Ionic/angularjs/pouchdb

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am working to collect and store personal info / pic locally on PouchDB using ionic/angularjs. Then i would sync remotely to a server at a later time.
However, i have an array to collect the info, but i do not know how to store the pic using same array although i am able to display it in pictureUrl. Please, i would appreciate your kind help.

NOTE: The pic needs to be stored immediately i snap and click save.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [PouchDB guide to attachments](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html)? There are lot of live examples in there of working with images and storing them in PouchDB, which you can test right in your browser. :)

Comment: Thanks so much sir, but the link doesn't provide the answer to my question or may be i do not understand it. However, i am just trying to add a pix to the sample code i got from this link https://github.com/ashteya/ionic-tutorial-pouchdb . And i would be so grateful if you can put me through.